# OpenNMS Windows send-event.pl , how to use the script?

Tags: opennms

i just installed OpenNMS. I want to send some events (i use windows), but i do not know how to do that. I do not know how to use send-event.pl script. Can someone give me an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a recent version of OpenNMS Horizon you can post OpenNMS events via ReST and you don't need the send-event Perl script anymore. The Windows equivalent to curl is [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-5.1) which can be called with something like:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

You can send any event in XML format to the events interface. The events which come with OpenNMS are in the ${OPENNMS_HOME}/etc/events folder. You can also create your own ones. Here is an example to send an event which tells OpenNMS Horizon to reload a Node requisition from a remote inventory:

```
curl -u admin \
-X POST \
-d "<event><uei>uei.opennms.org/internal/importer/reloadImport</uei><parms><parm><parmName>url</parmName><value>http://my-inventory.acme/requisitions/Mail-Server</value></parm></parms></event>" \
-H "Content-Type: application/xml" http://my-opennms-server:8980/opennms/rest/events
```

I hope this helps